# Executing Error - Program stops working (C)

Tags: c

I need to write a simple program that reads numbers from a file, then stores those numbers in an array. The last number in the file is 0 so the program knows when to reading.

When I execute the program, Dec C++ crashes. I went online for solutions and changed the settings accordingly but that didn't work. I ran other programs I have and it works fine, which makes me think there's something wrong with the code.

Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int i, j=0, k;
    int values[20];
    FILE*ptr;

    ptr = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    fscanf(ptr, "%d", &i);
    while (i=!0){
        values[j]=i;
        j++;
        fscanf(ptr, "%d", &i);
    }

    for (k=0; k<20; k++)
        printf("%d\n", values[k]);

    fclose (ptr);

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: What is "Dec C++"? This is C, not C++.

Comment: The first `fscanf` is missing the `&` before `i`.

Comment: I apologize, "Dev C++". It is the name of the program I use

Comment: @Barmar Does this kind of question qualify for flagging as "caused by a simple typographical error"?

Comment: Still not working, even after adding the &i

Comment: @Arc676 It did until he edited it to remove that typo.

Comment: @Mr.Delicious Wait a second. Was the `&` missing in the original program, or was it a copying error? Please don't change the question.

Comment: Are you sure there are no more than 20 numbers in the file?

Comment: Yes, the & was missing. I fixed it for future people who might look at this post. Fixing it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Another typo:

```
while (i=!0){
```

should be:

```
while (i != 0){
```

Your code was assigning `!0` to `i`, instead of comparing `i` with `0`. `!0` is `1`, so you had an infinite loop, and you were writing beyond the bounds of the array.

Also note that if the file has more than 20 numbers in it, you'll write outside the array. And if it has fewer than 20 numbers, the loop that prints `values[k]` will read uninitialized array entries.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that are wrong with the code:

- You are not checking for error after opening input.txt
- While i=!0 is syntactically correct it probably does not do what you want !0 is 1, so it is the same as i=1, you are putting value 1 into i

To help you with debugging:

- add printf() statements to your code to verify that you reached a certain line and to check the values of the variables
- learn to use a debugger